How to prove the direct product of identification map is not an identification map

How to prove the direct product of identification map is not an identification map? Let ${X}_{1} = \left\lbrack  {0, 1}\right\rbrack   \times$ $\mathbb{Z}$, on ${X}_{1}$ we have an equivalence relation $\sim$, which collapse $\{ \left( {0, n}\right)  \mid  n \in  \mathbb{Z}\}$ to one point, and other equivalence classes are singeleton. Let $Y_1={X}_{1}/ \sim$. Assume further ${X}_{2} = {Y}_{2} = \mathbb{Q}$, then the projection ${f}_{1} : {X}_{1} \rightarrow  {Y}_{1}$ and the identity map ${f}_{2} : {X}_{2} \rightarrow  {Y}_{2}$ are both identification map. How to prove that
$$
f={f}_{1} \times  {f}_{2} : {X}_{1} \times  {X}_{2} \rightarrow  {Y}_{1} \times  {Y}_{2}, (x_1,x_2)\mapsto(y_1,y_2)
$$
is not an identification map?

My attempt: $Y_1$ can be vewied as $\{r\cos\frac{2\pi}{n},r\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}; 0\leq r\leq 1, n\geq 1\}$, which looks like a star from $0$.
Can we not $f$ is not continuous? A closed subset $$A=\{((\cos 2\pi/n,\sin 2\pi/n),0); n\geq 1\}\cup \{((1,0),0)\}$$ whose preimage is not closed?
I guess it may induce discontiuity of $f$ aound $[0,1]\times \{0\}$, but I have no such evidence...Help me, thank you.

identification map?

Synonym of quotient map I believe.

@Malady Yes, just the quotient map.
